# Explaining calculation of variance of $X(s)\vert X(t)$ where $X(t) = At+B$, and $A,B$ are independently gaussian

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I need help with this question- it’s been bugging me for a while and I can’t figure it out. 
$A,B \sim N_{[0,1]}$ independent random variables.
the solution asserts that $X(s)$ and $X(t)$ are jointly gaussian because they’re a linear transformation of $(A,B)^T$ which is a random gaussian vector, why are jointly gaussians implying that $X(t)|X(s) \sim N$?

moreover, I can’t figure out how they computed the variance for $X(t)|X(s)$.

$$\sigma^2 = \text{Var}(X(t)) - \frac{\text{CoV}(X(t),X(s))^2}{\text{Var}(X(s))} = \mathbb{E}(X^2(t)) - \frac{(E(X(t)X(s))^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2(s)]}$$
what formula is used here? from that point I can complete the calculation but I don’t understand it’s beginning and the reasoning behind the conditional distribution being a gaussian. any help is massively appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are bivariate normal with mean zero, variances $\sigma^2_X$, $\sigma^2_Y$, and covariance $\sigma_{XY}$, then they can be written as linear combinations of standard normal random variables $U$ and $V$ like so:
\begin{align}
X &= \frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y} U + \sqrt{\sigma_X^2 - \frac{\sigma_{XY}^2}{\sigma_Y^2}} V \\
Y &= \sigma_Y U
\end{align}
with the coefficients chosen to produce the correct variances and covariance.

From this transformed representation, it's now obvious from the independence of $U$ and $V$ that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ (which is equivalent to the conditional distribution of $X$ given $U$) is:
\begin{align}
X|Y &\sim N\left(\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y}U,\sigma_X^2-\frac{\sigma_{XY}^2}{\sigma_Y^2}\right) \\
&=N\left(\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_Y^2} Y,\sigma_X^2-\frac{\sigma_{XY}^2}{\sigma_Y^2}\right)
\end{align}

If you take $X=X(t)$ and $Y=Y(s)$, the variance expression here matches your expression for the variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: I see, thank you!!